# Как оставить два знака после запятой у всех выводимых ответов одним разом?

Tags: python, функции, импорт, round

подскажите, как оставить только два знака после запятой у всех выводимых ответов функции?
Например в этом.

```
import math as m
x = int(input('x: '))
def kvadrat():
    d = x * m.sqrt(2)
    p = x * 4
    s = (1 / 2) * d ** 2
    return (d, p, s,) 
print(kvadrat())
```

Округлять каждое значение отдельно считаю тратой времени, буду благодарен каждому за Вашу посильную помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
return tuple(map(lambda x: round(x, 2), (d, p, s)))
```

Каждое значение из кортежа округляется и обратно возвращается в кортеж. Хотя, мне кажется, проще каждое округлить.

Comment: @Yarpen не за что)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это поможет.

```
return tuple(map(lambda x: round(x, 2), (d, p, s)))
```

Пример вывода при **x = 5**:

```
(7.07, 20, 25.0)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, Ваш вариант работает.

Comment: @Yarpen Всегда рад помочь

Comment: Принятый ответ был на 1 мин. 20 сек. раньше. 1:1 копия.

Comment: @0xdb Сам удивился. Написал, страница обновилась и два ответа.

Comment: @Klef Просто совпало :) Попробуйте изменить, чтобы отличалось, например, добавте воспроизводимый пример с данными и выводом результата.

Answer (score 0):

Более явно:

```
return tuple(round(i, 2) for i in (d, p, s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно сделать с проверкой на принадлежность типу float.

```
return tuple([round(i, 2) if isinstance(i, float) else i for i in (d, p, s)])
```

Можно применить форматирование *(здесь все будет с двумя знаками после запятой)*.

```
return tuple(['%.2f' % i for i in (d, p, s)])
```